# On the distribution of sample intraclass correlation for normal data

Tags: distributions, correlation, multivariate-normal-distribution, intraclass-correlation

Consider i.i.d random vectors $\boldsymbol X_1,\boldsymbol X_2,\ldots,\boldsymbol X_n$ having a $p$-variate normal distribution $N_p(\boldsymbol \mu,\Sigma)$ where $\Sigma$ has compound symmetry of the form $\Sigma=\sigma^2((1-\rho)I_p+\rho\mathbf1_p\mathbf1_p')$. Assume $n>p$ and that $\Sigma$ is positive definite.

So the data is of the form $(X_{ij})_{1\le i\le n,1\le j\le p}$, denoting $n$ groups each of size $p$.

Define the grand mean $$\overline X=\frac1{np}\sum_{i,j}X_{ij}$$ and total sum of squares $$S^2=\sum_{i,j}(X_{ij}-\overline X)^2$$

Sample intraclass correlation coefficient is then the quantity

$$R_{I}=\frac1{(p-1)S^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{1\le j\ne j'\le p}(X_{ij}-\overline X)(X_{ij'}-\overline X)$$

In C.R. Rao's *[Linear Statistical Inference and its Applications](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.40834/page/n223/mode/2up)* (2nd ed.), it is shown under the special case $\boldsymbol \mu=\mu\mathbf1_p$ that $R_I$ has the following density when $\rho=0$:

$$f_{R_I}(r)\propto (1-r)^{n(p-1)/2-1}(1+r(p-1))^{(n-1)/2-1}\quad,\, r\in\left[-\frac1{p-1},1\right] \tag{1}$$

This is deduced by proving that $1-R_I$ has a certain scaled Beta distribution when $\rho=0$. The case $\rho\ne 0$ is also discussed briefly.

I have a couple of questions:

1. Is the assumption $\boldsymbol \mu=\mu\mathbf1_p$ necessary for deriving the distribution of $R_I$ (both for zero and non-zero $\rho$) or can it be derived for any mean vector $\boldsymbol \mu$?
2. Is there any connection between the distribution of $R_I$ and that of the sample correlation $R$ when $p=2$ and $\rho=0$?

When $\rho=0$ (and without assuming $\boldsymbol \mu=\mu\mathbf1_2$), it is known that $R$ has density $$f_R(r)\propto (1-r^2)^{n/2-2} \quad,\, r\in [-1,1] \tag{2}$$

It can be seen that $(1)$ and $(2)$ are quite similar when $p=2$. Does this signify anything?